# Processing or Java: get Window Position?

Tags: processing

I'm writing a sketch in Processing and I'm curious how I can get the position of the OS's window that the sketch lives in. If I use `getPosition()` (part of `java.awt`) I only get the position of the viewport within the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getLocationOnScreen()` inherited from `java.awt.Component`, but you need to make sure the applet `isShowing()` first:

```
void draw(){
  if(frame.isShowing()) println(frame.getLocationOnScreen());
}
```

or slightly more graphical:

```
void draw(){
  if(frame.isShowing()) {
    java.awt.Point pt = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
    background(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(map(pt.x,0,displayWidth,0,width),//use screenWidth instead of displayWidth in Processing 1.5.1 or older
         map(pt.y,0,displayHeight,0,height),//use screenHeight instead of displayHeight in Processing 1.5.1 or older
         10,10);
  }
}
```

where

```
Frame frame = ( (PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) ((PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative()).getFrame();
```

(For other renderers such as `P2D` or `FX2D` check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107750/java-and-processing-3-0-frame-class-deprecated-is-there-an-alternative/55957053#55957053))

Comment: there is no method named `isShowing()` in PApplet class

Comment: @Yeppii good point! Thank you ! Those methods belong to the frame. I've updated the answer above