# Java and Processing 3.0 “frame” class deprecated, is there an alternative?

Tags: java, processing, frame

so [Processing](http://www.processing.org) used to have a "frame" class which allowed for some versatile functionality. I'm trying to get the location of the PApplet window onscreen but without the "frame" class, I can't seem to to do it.

The old way:

```
int fX = frame.getX();
```

or

```
int fX = frame.getLocationOnScreen().x;
```

The whole thing is supposed to be dynamic, so setting the window location in Processings setup() is not an option.

Hope somebody can help,

Greetings!
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best off just using the old `frame` variable.

For most things like this, you should use the new `surface` variable, which is of type `PSurface`. You can view the source for `PSurface` [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PSurface.java). Reading that, we see that unfortunately, the `surface` variable doesn't give us access to the frame's position.

Since you can't get to the location from the `surface` variable, you have to go a level deeper and get the **native** component (in the default case, a `SmoothCanvas` which extends an awt `Canvas`). I figured this out by looking at the source for `PSurfaceAWT` available [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/awt/PSurfaceAWT.java).

The code for that looks a little gross, since you have to do some casting:

```
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas;

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);

  int x = ( (SmoothCanvas) ((PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative()).getFrame().getX();
  text("x: " + x , 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what I want, thank you! Also sadly some of the functions, that came with the frame class seem to no longer work, so that wouldn't have been an option. (Like the .getX(), which only returns 0)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's excellent answer here is a function that uses that along with the equivalent for the `P2D`,`P3D` and `FX2D` renderers:

```
void setup(){
  size(300,300,FX2D);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  text(getLocationOnScreen().toString(),10,15);
}

PVector getLocationOnScreen(){
  PVector location = new PVector();
  // JAVA2D
  if(surface instanceof processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT){
    java.awt.Frame frame = ( (processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) ((processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative()).getFrame();
    java.awt.Point point = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
    location.set(point.x,point.y);
  }
  // P2D, P3D
  else if(surface instanceof processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL){
    com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow window = (com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow)(((PSurfaceJOGL)surface).getNative());
    com.jogamp.nativewindow.util.Point point = window.getLocationOnScreen(new com.jogamp.nativewindow.util.Point());
    location.set(point.getX(),point.getY());
  }
  // FX2D
  else if(surface instanceof processing.javafx.PSurfaceFX){
    javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas canvas = (javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas)((processing.javafx.PSurfaceFX)surface).getNative();
    javafx.geometry.Point2D point = canvas.localToScreen(0,0);
    location.set((float)point.getX(),(float)point.getY()); 
  }
  return location;
}
```

(Code code've been more elegant using imports, but for I've left the fully qualified class names in so it's easier to copy/paste/test the function in new sketches)

Comment: If using an external IDE (not sure about the processing editor), JavaFX is no longer included by default, so the last else if statement will need to be removed, unless using an implementation of JavaFX, one of which can be found here: https://openjfx.io/

Comment: Is there also a way to get the screen coordinate for the surface's drawable area? (with the code from this answer, you're still left with the puzzle of figuring out which screen point the sketch point (0,0) maps to due to the title bar and frame border etc)

Comment: That's a very good point Max. Unfortunately I can't update the answer right now, but I'll look into it later today. (P.S. Many thanks for the wealth of knowledge shared through ProcessingJS throughout the years)