# How would I set the window size to windowed fullscreen?

Tags: java, window, processing

How do I set the window size to "windowed fullscreen"?

The best I can do is:

```
surface.setLocation(0, 0);
surface.setSize(displayWidth, displayHeight);
```

however it doesn't fit because of the taskbar and `setLocation(0, 0)` doesn't set the position to exactly the top left corner (it is a little off to the right and bottom)

I am using Windows 10 with Processing 4.0b2. I am also not using the processing application, but using the core jar as a library.

Comment: Which GUI lib are you using? Swing or JavaFx?

Comment: Processing? I just took the core.jar file out of the library files for the application and used it as a library in Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`fullScreen()`](https://processing.org/reference/fullScreen_.html) function you can use.

In `setup()` simply replace your `size();` call with `fullscreen();`.

Check out the reference for other uses, for example:

- fullscreen with the OpenGL P2D renderer (`fullScreen(P2D);`)
- fullscreen on the 2nd monitor (`fullScreen(2);`) only
- fullscsreen spanning two monitors (`fullscreen(SPAN);`)

Comment: I'm aware of this, but what I'm going for is "windowed fullscreen" where the screen takes up everything except the taskbar and still shows the title bar.

Comment: I see. I wish I knew a clever way of accessing the title bar dimensions in Processing. If the issue the window appears a bit to the right and bottom, instead of `surface.setLocation(0, 0);` can you get way with a negative offset (e.g. `surface.setLocation(-3,-26);`) ?

Comment: I've fiddle with the numbers and narrowed it down to (-6, -3) but this is still slightly off and I don't know if it will be off or not for other people.

Comment: which renderer do you use in Processing (? default Java AWT(`JAVA2D`, JavaFX (`FX2D`), OpenGL (`P2D`,`P3D`) ? Each has it's specific way of handling windowing. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107750/java-and-processing-3-0-frame-class-deprecated-is-there-an-alternative/55957053#55957053) does the reverse of what you want: gets the position instead of setting it, but it shows how to access the hierarchy of each renderer. Hopefully somewhere up the hierarchy there are methods to measure the title bar height. 